# Stored procedure returns no rows with SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqldataadapter

I'm new to using `SqlDataAdpter` and I'm trying to execute a stored procedure. The stored procedure executes successfully but no rows are returned. I've used SQL Server Profiler to monitor the call and it runs successfully (I can copy and execute the query from profiler without modifying it and get results).

I have the following:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    DataSet results = null;

    try
    {
        string connectionString = // ... my connection
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString );
        string query = @"usp_mySP";

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
        sqlAdpt.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        var dataDate = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@DataDate", Value = DateTime.Now };
        var idList = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@IDList", Value = "1231,2324,0833" };                 

        sqlAdpt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(dataDate);
        sqlAdpt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(idList);

        results = new DataSet();
        sqlAdpt.Fill(results);

        sqlAdpt.Dispose();
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {               
        throw new Exception("Exception:" + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.Close();
    }

    return View(results);
}
```

When I inspect the `DataSet` through the debugger, it always returns 0 rows.

Please help with what I'm doing wrong?

**Note:** I've also tried (but do NOT prefer) executing as a SQL command:

```
EXEC usp_mySP @DataDate, @IDList
```

and it didn't work either as I got `int` to `varchar` conversion errors.

Comment: Perhaps verify that you have `set nocount on` at the beginning of your SP.

Comment: Tip for debugging: Use sql server profiler and verify what is sent to the sql server instance. Also see what the return is (should have rows or some other property). You can also capture the exact sql command and reexecute in management studio to see what the result was.

Comment: did you use `SQL Profiler` to capture what SQL is going to server? Did you debug your SP? It  may be helpful to see your logic inside your SP.  Sometimes the date format sent by .Net may not be matching up with the date format expected by DB Server!!

Comment: Run your program in  debug mode and see what value you get for 'connectionString' - from the looks of your code, string connectionString = ... doesn't seem to have any value set. The line is not terminated with ';'

Comment: It was the `set nocount on`. It was not there. It now works Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason was because of `set nocount on`. I added it to my sp and it works. Thank you everyone for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to add `SqlParameter` using `SqlCommand` like this :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.parameter.addwithvalue(@DataDate,DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: That's a valid way to do this - but so is the approach used in the question. This is definitely **not** the reason for the issues ....